# CNET developer api to get detailed product specification

Tags: api, product

i am trying to use CNET developer api to get a list of detailed product specification but what what i can get now is basic product details 
Apple iOS 5, Apple A5X, IEEE 802.11n, IEEE 802.11b, IEEE 802.11a, IEEE 802.11g, Bluetooth 4.0, 7.3 in x 0.4 in x 9.5 in, 9.7 in TFT active matrix - LED backlight - Yes, 23 oz

but i need the details
something like this

General
Product Type    Tablet
Operating System    Apple iOS 5
First Seen On Google Shopping    March 2011
Display
Type    9.7" IPS TFT - LED backlight
Resolution  1024 x 768 ( 132 ppi )
Touchscreen Multi-Touch
Features    Fingerprint resistant oleophobic coating
Processor
Processor   Apple A5
Processor Clock Speed   1 GHz
Number of Cores Dual-Core

and not necessarily use CNET apis i am fine with any other source of product information 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Could you please format properties which you receive from CNET and expect?

I'm representative of http://aerse.com. We strive to provide the most detailed properties with strict validation of property values. Have a look at [Nokia N900](http://aerse.com/f?n=N900&v=Nokia)

If you fine with multiple results for single product (for example, search "N900", get many of "N900" products) you could try Amazon [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).

Also you could have a look at APIs here: http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Shopping